# MySQL: Safely auto increment MySQL field based on MAX() subquery upon insert

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `articleid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `sequence` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `comments4` (`articleid`) USING BTREE,
 UNIQUE KEY `comments5` (`articleid`, `sequence`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `comments3` (`articleid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

When I insert a data, the  `sequence` should autoincrement based on the MAX value. Everything works fine until two parellel request hits resulting to a MySQL error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '2137092-3' for key 'comments5'

I tried to resolve this with Transaction with Subquery but it turned out to cause massive performance issues.

How else can I resolve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the query that generates this error.

Comment: Leaving aside the question actually being asked, for me the important question is *Why?* You already have an auto increment field which gives you sequence and unique identification, MySQL's LIMIT clause provides a means for pagination, and obtaining a count by "parent" record is not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Put the select Max() ..... and the insert in a TRANSACTION. Max(9 is always a issue in INNODB

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - yes 100 %, but i have only edit my answer. i delete the second - thanks